# Why Does My HTML Select Element Render Empty Options on First Load Even with 'v-if' Condition?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to present the collection in MongoDB database as a option in html select in a component;
So i made an API endpoint and then store the result- the array of collection names in a const in pinia store.

```
const databaseOptions = ref([])
 try {
      const response = await axios.get('/getDBList')
      console.log(response.data)
      if (databaseOptions.value.length !== 0) return
      databaseOptions.value.push(...response.data.data)
```

the function is async and it takes time to get the data.

then in component I import the store and access the data:

```
const databaseOptions = ref([...globalStore.databaseOptions])

 <select
          class="tex-center mb-2 min-w-[10rem] rounded-3xl p-2 font-semibold"
          v-model="selectedColletcion"
          v-if="globalStore.databaseOptions.length > 0"
        >
          <option v-for="db in databaseOptions" :key="db.name" :value="db">
            {{ db }}
          </option>
        </select>
```

and the problem is that the component renders, and the select renders, but there are no options in it. If i reload, or switch the component and go back to this, the select options are loaded i have access to them. But when i enter the component for the first time, the select is empty.
First of all, why does select redner at all, if i have a `v-if` , and then, why it the select is empty of first load and how to fix it?

Comment: In the v-if, you use `globalStore.databaseOptions` but in the v-for, it is just `databaseOptions`. Is it that?

Comment: in component i have: const databaseOptions = ref([...globalStore.databaseOptions])

Comment: You should add this to your question. It will create a copy of the values in `globalStore.databaseOptions`. The copy is not reactive. If data in the store changes, those changes will not reflect in the `databaseOptions` ref. So if you create the copy before data was loaded, you are stuck with empty values. Why do you use a copy at all?